# Unable to update counter if box containing group of checkboxes unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes for categories. When any of them clicked, a list of related subjects for that category will be listed out in table with id `boxA`.

I set a counter that can count the number of subjects being clicked inside the `boxA` and it works well. But for the below scenario it doesn't work as expected!

## Scenario

User click say category A,related subjects will be shown in the `boxA`. The user may click any number of subjects there. After that the user decides to add more category, so he/she clicks say category D, related subjects will be listed out. By this time, I noticed, the previously checked subjects are automatically unchecked which I wonder why?

And the counter I set, not showing the correct figure when the `boxA` is empty. It supposed to show 0 when none of them checked but it still shows number of checks prior to choosing the category D. How to make the counter recognize if none of the checkboxes is checked or `boxA` is empty.

Or easier and proper solution would be, how to make the previously checked checkboxes don't loose the checked status when new category added in? Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

HTML for the cehckboxes inside `boxA`

```
<input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="sub['.$subjects_id.']" id="sub" value="" onchange="myFunction()">
```

## Script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on('change', '[id^=sub][type=checkbox]', function () {
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $('#count').text($(this).length);
     }


});
</script>
```

EDITED script for subjects

```
function sendtobox(param,param2)
            {
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              if (this.responseText !== null) {
                var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
                //ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; // append in front
                 jQuery(ajaxElm).append(this.responseText);
               }

             }
            }
```

script for categories:

```
<script>
       $("#slider1").change(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       sendtobox(value, $("input[type=checkbox]#level").val());
      });

    $("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]").change(function() {  
     var selectedval = $(this).val();
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
        sendtobox(selectedval, $("#slider1").val());
     }
      else {
        $("th."+selectedval).remove();//controls removing from boxA

     }
    });
</script>
```

HTML for categories:

```
<ul class="box small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                  <li>
                      <div class="level_1">
                       <input type="checkbox" name="level[Primary]" id="level_1" class="level" value="1">
                        <label for="level_1"><span class="level_label">Primary</span></label>
                      </div>

                  </li>
                  <li>
                       <div class="level_2">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="level[Upper Secondary]" id="level_2" class="level" value="3">
                      <label for="level_2"><span class="level_label">Upper&nbsp;Secondary</span></label>
                      </div>
                  </li> 
                  <li>
                      <div class="level_3">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="level[University]" id="level_3" class="level" value="5">
                        <label for="level_3"><span class="level_label">University</span></label>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <div class="level_4">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="level[Lower Secondary]" id="level_4" class="level" value="2">
                        <label for="level_4"><span class="level_label">Lower&nbsp;Secondary</span></label>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <div class="level_5">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="level[Pre University]" id="level_5" class="level" value="4">
                        <label for="level_5"><span class="level_label">Pre&nbsp;University</span></label>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <div class="level_6">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="level[Other]" id="level_6" class="level" value="6">
                        <label for="level_6"><span class="level_label">Other</span></label>
                      </div>

              </ul>
```

structure for subject

```
<table class="show small-8 medium-8 large-8 columns small-centered medium-centered large-centered" id="boxA">
                <?php



                  if($last_category != $levels) 
   {
    $last_category = $levels;

    echo '<tr><th class="' . $q .' title">'. $levels;

   }
echo '<table id="inner"><tr><td style="width:50%" class="subject">'. $subjects . '</td><td style="width:5%;"><input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="sub['.$subjects_id.']" id="sub" value="" onchange="myFunction()"><br></td>';
echo'<td style="width:30%;"><span class="test"><input type="textbox" name="rate2['.$subjects_id.']" class="rate2" value=""  placeholder="'.$placeholder.'" id="rate2"></span></td></tr></table>';

if($last_category != $levels)
echo '</th></tr>';
                    ?>      
    </table>
```

> NOW with the updated script, subjects checkboxes doesn't loose it's
>   status and counts well. But when I uncheck the category from boxA the
>   count doesn't decrease!
>
> ```
> $(document).on('change', '[id^=sub][type=checkbox]', function () {
>     $('#count').text($('[id^=sub][type=checkbox]:checked').length); //How to put a control that will check for category also to increase and decrease the count?
> });
> ```

Comment: Are you re-adding all of the related subjects each time a category is checked/unchecked, or are you individually appending/removing them?

Comment: I'm appending them @PatrickEvans

Comment: if (this.responseText !== null) {
                var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
                ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; // append in front
               }

Comment: You are effectively re-adding them all then, as setting innerHTML makes the browser re-render the element and its contents (effectively recreating each of your checkboxes) so they lose whatever state they had. use jQuery's [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)/[prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method instead

Comment: Can I append like this: ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText.append(ajaxElm.innerHTML);......_but this is not working though

Comment: `$(this).length` will always be `1` ....`this` is the checkbox element that changed and there can only be one `this` in an event handler

Comment: tried this to no avail:   var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
              {
     ajaxElm.innerHTML .append(responseText);
               }

Comment: are you repeating ID's? They must be unique in a page by defintiion. Show more html and code and better yet create a demo in jsfiddle,net that replicates problem

Comment: Since you are using jQuery you would append like so: `jQuery(ajaxElm).append(this.responseText);`

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks it works for subject level...Meaning it doesn't loose the checked statea nd counter counts perfectly BUT when I uncheck the categories from boxA, the counter still keeps previous counts instead of decreasing the count!  I posted more of my code, can you help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the counter keeps the previous count if you uncheck categories is because when you remove the subjects from the table with `$("th."+selectedval).remove();`, you aren't telling the counter to update. So to update the counter, you need to call `$('#count').text($('[id^=sub][type=checkbox]:checked').length);` after you remove the rows in the table.

Though a better solution would probably be to encapsulate it in a function just in case you ever want to add to this task of updating the count:

```
function updateCount () {
  $('#count').text($('[id^=sub][type=checkbox]:checked').length);
}

// ...

$(document).on('change', '[id^=sub][type=checkbox]', updateCount);

// ...

$("input[type=checkbox][id^=level]").change(function() {  
  var selectedval = $(this).val();
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var selectedtext = $(this).next().text();
    sendtobox(selectedval, $("#slider1").val());
  } else {
    $("th."+selectedval).remove();
    updateCount();
  }
});
```